# Php-Divide Paragraph by number of character?

Tags: php

Dear Sir i want to divide paragraph by number of character.
My aim is in one single page script.
1)one box for the input test
2)and other box for the output which divide by character
i.e. if there is 100 character in paragraph and i divide by the 10 character per box and 10 box will be output

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

I found this code but how to do this in the box??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to used this code for 20 character

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap("<p>".$text."</p>", 28, "</p><br><p>");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

Output :

```
<p>The quick brown fox</p><br><p>jumped over the lazy</p><br><p>dog.</p>
```

Comment: how to create the box for this ???

Comment: create one box for the input??

Comment: output :<p>The quick brown fox</p><br><p>jumped over the lazy</p><br><p>dog.</p>

Comment: sir i want to make one box where user can enter the text and by clicking the button it will divide by number of character?